# I want to see the properties of the file

Tags: files

I am using Files.
When viewing attributes in a file, I want to see the properties corresponding to Type.
Do you have an Addon to view properties in Files?

I do not want to use Files with less functionality.
Do you have any other programs?

I can see the image only properties.
Video, mp3 can not see the property.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably uninstalled totem, try re install it, audio and video info will come back

Answer (score 2):

**exiftool** is good for pulling out metadata

Example:

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
exiftool myfile.mp4 | grep -i type
```

There's also the **file** command

```
file myfile.mp4
```

Comment: `exiftool` package is not available in repositories for ubuntu 18.04... The user wants to display media files info in nautilus

Comment: @cmak.fr Well, it's actually called `libimage-exiftool-perl` and it _is_ in the standard repositories.

Comment: You're right. I changed the package to install from ```exiftool``` to ```libimage-exiftool-perl```